# Python Homework - Inventory program with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Not sure if anyone can help. This is my first class so I'm very new to python and programming in general. I have a program for my Python class that I am stuck on. I have it doing the basics, but cannot figure out how to check the inventory quantity against the user inputted quantity. I know the nested if statement is incorrect ( I left that in so I had something) but that's what I'm struggling with.

Also..I have only laid out the ending part of the program which is why my input is blank.

supplier_data is what was provided to us by the instructor.

```
    supplier_data = '{"parts": ["sprocket", "gizmo", "widget", "dodad"], "sprocket": 
    {"price": 3.99, "quantity": 32}, "gizmo": {"price": 7.98, "quantity": 2}, "widget": 
    {"price": 14.32, "quantity": 4}, "dodad": {"price": 0.5, "quantity": 0}}'


    import json
    json.loads(supplier_data)
    new_data = json.loads(supplier_data)
    print(new_data)

    print("Welcome to the parts ordering system, please enter in a part name, followed 
    by a quantity.\n")
    print("Parts for order are:\n")
    print("sprocket")
    print("gizmo")
    print("widget")
    print("dodad\n\n")

    order = {}
    inventory = True
    while inventory:
        part_input = input("Please enter in a part name, or quit to exit: ")
        if part_input in new_data.keys():
           quantity_input = int(input("Please enter in a quantity to order: "))
           order[part_input] = quantity_input
           print(order)
           if quantity_input >= new_data['sprocket']['quantity']:
                print("Error, only" + new_data['sprocket']['quantity'] + part_input + " 
                are available!")
                continue

        elif part_input == "quit":
             inventory = False

        else:
             print("Error, part does not exist, try again.")
```

This is what I get currently when I run it.

```
Welcome to the parts ordering system, please enter in a part name, followed by a quantity.

Parts for order are:

sprocket
gizmo
widget
dodad


Please enter in a part name, or quit to exit: sprocket
Please enter in a quantity to order: 3
{'sprocket': 3}
Please enter in a part name, or quit to exit: gizmo
Please enter in a quantity to order: 1
{'sprocket': 3, 'gizmo': 1}
Please enter in a part name, or quit to exit: widget
Please enter in a quantity to order: 8
{'sprocket': 3, 'gizmo': 1, 'widget': 8}
Please enter in a part name, or quit to exit: dodad
Please enter in a quantity to order: 1
{'sprocket': 3, 'gizmo': 1, 'widget': 8, 'dodad': 1}
Please enter in a part name, or quit to exit: quit
Your Order

Total: $
Thank you for using the parts ordering system!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: can you explain what your code should do in the question, it's hard to know what you want to do from the code that you say doesn't do what you want to do ... so what do you want to do ?

Comment: Sorry about that I have never posted here before. We were provided an inventory and the user inputs what part they want and how many. If they are done they hit quit and we print out a statement. What I am stuck on is one of the conditions which is to check the available quantity against what the user inputs. So if they put in 3 'dodads'....it should print an error message because there are 0 in the inventory.

Comment: Hi @Jenn and welcome to SO. If you are new here, you might want to start by taking the [tour], and then reading through [ask]. This will tell you what is expected, so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that also performs the discount of each order's quantity from supplier data, whenever an order is placed:

```py
import json
import pprint

supplier_data = """{"parts": ["sprocket", "gizmo", "widget", "dodad"], 
"sprocket": {"price": 3.99, "quantity": 32}, "gizmo": {"price": 7.98, "quantity": 2}, 
"widget": {"price": 14.32, "quantity": 4}, "dodad": {"price": 0.5, "quantity": 0}}"""

json.loads(supplier_data)
new_data = json.loads(supplier_data)

print(f"{' Inventory Program ':=^50}")
print(
    "Welcome to the parts ordering system, please enter in a part name, "
    "followed "
    "by a quantity.\n"
)
print(
    "Parts to order can be one of:\n- "
    + "\n- ".join(new_data["parts"])
    + "\n\n"
)

order = {}
inventory = True

while inventory:

    total_parts_left = sum(
        value.get("quantity", 0) if isinstance(value, dict) else 0
        for value in new_data.values()
    )
    if total_parts_left <= 0:
        pprint.pprint(
            "There are no more quantities left for any part. Exiting..."
        )
        inventory = False
        break

    part_input = input(
        "Please enter a part name, or quit/q to exit\nAvailable parts:\n- "
        + "\n- ".join(
            filter(lambda key: new_data[key]["quantity"] > 0, new_data["parts"])
        )
        + "\n\nPart name:"
    )
    if part_input in new_data.keys():
        quantity_input = int(
            input(
                f"Please enter in a quantity to order ("
                f"{new_data[part_input]['quantity']:,} units available):"
            )
        )

        if quantity_input > new_data[part_input]["quantity"]:
            print(
                f"Error: only {new_data[part_input]['quantity']} units are "
                f"available for {part_input}!"
            )
            continue
        else:
            order[part_input] = order.get(part_input, 0) + quantity_input
            print(
                f'\nYour order of {quantity_input:,} units for part "'
                f'{part_input}" was fullfilled!\n'
            )
            pprint.pprint("Updated order:")
            pprint.pprint(order)
            print("\n" + "=" * 50 + "\n")

            # Note: comment the next line if you don't want to update the
            # `supplier_data`
            #       inventory of each part, after an order gets placed.
            new_data[part_input]["quantity"] -= quantity_input

    elif part_input in ["quit", "q"]:
        inventory = False
    else:
        print(
            f'Error: part "{part_input}" does not exist, choose one of the '
            f"following:\n- "
            + "\n- ".join(new_data["parts"])
            + "\n\nThen try again..."
        )

order_cost = sum(
    new_data[key]["price"] * value if isinstance(new_data[key], dict) else 0
    for key, value in order.items()
)

if order_cost > 0:
    print(f"\n{' Your Order ':=^50}")
    pprint.pprint(order)
    print(f"Total Cost: ${order_cost:,.2f}")
else:
    print("You didn't order any part...")
```

**Output Example:**

```py
"""
=============== Inventory Program ================
Welcome to the parts ordering system, please enter in a part name, followed by a quantity.

Parts to order can be one of:
- sprocket
- gizmo
- widget
- dodad


Please enter a part name, or quit/q to exit
Available parts:
- sprocket
- gizmo
- widget

Part name: sprocket
Please enter in a quantity to order (32 units available): 32

Your order of 32 units for part "sprocket" was fullfilled!

'Updated order:'
{'sprocket': 32}

==================================================

Please enter a part name, or quit/q to exit
Available parts:
- gizmo
- widget

Part name: gizmo
Please enter in a quantity to order (2 units available): 2

Your order of 2 units for part "gizmo" was fullfilled!

'Updated order:'
{'gizmo': 2, 'sprocket': 32}

==================================================

Please enter a part name, or quit/q to exit
Available parts:
- widget

Part name: widget
Please enter in a quantity to order (4 units available): 5
Error: only 4 units are available for widget!
Please enter a part name, or quit/q to exit
Available parts:
- widget

Part name: widget
Please enter in a quantity to order (4 units available): 4

Your order of 4 units for part "widget" was fullfilled!

'Updated order:'
{'gizmo': 2, 'sprocket': 32, 'widget': 4}

==================================================

'There are no more quantities left for any part. Exiting...'

=================== Your Order ===================
{'gizmo': 2, 'sprocket': 32, 'widget': 4}
Total Cost: $200.92
"""
```

### Commented Solution

Here's a commented version of the solution:

```py
import json
import pprint

# 1. First, we load the `supplier_data` into a dictionary using `json.loads()`.
#    The loaded dictionary will be stored inside a variable named `new_data`
supplier_data = """{"parts": ["sprocket", "gizmo", "widget", "dodad"], 
"sprocket": {"price": 3.99, "quantity": 32}, "gizmo": {"price": 7.98, "quantity": 2}, 
"widget": {"price": 14.32, "quantity": 4}, "dodad": {"price": 0.5, "quantity": 0}}"""

json.loads(supplier_data)
new_data = json.loads(supplier_data)

print(f"{' Inventory Program ':=^50}")
print(
    "Welcome to the parts ordering system, please enter in a part name, "
    "followed "
    "by a quantity.\n"
)
print(
    "Parts to order can be one of:\n- "
    + "\n- ".join(new_data["parts"])
    + "\n\n"
)

order = {}
inventory = True

# 2. Then, we create a `while` loop that will keep running until the user
#    decides to quit.
while inventory:

    # 3. Calculate the total number of parts left in the inventory.
    #    If there aren't any parts left, print a message to notify the user and
    #    exit the `while` loop.
    total_parts_left = sum(
        value. Get("quantity", 0) if isinstance(value, dict) else 0
        for value in new_data.values()
    )
    # 4. If the total number of parts left is less than or equal to 0, we print
    #    a message and exit the program.
    if total_parts_left <= 0:
        pprint.pprint(
            "There are no more quantities left for any part. Exiting..."
        )
        inventory = False
        break

    # 5. If the total number of parts left is greater than 0, we ask the user
    #    to enter a part name. The `filter` statement allows us to print the 
    #    parts that have a quantity greater than 0 left.
    part_input = input(
        "Please enter a part name, or quit/q to exit\nAvailable parts:\n- "
        + "\n- ".join(
            filter(lambda key: new_data[key]["quantity"] > 0, new_data["parts"])
        )
        + "\n\nPart name:"
    )
    # 6. If the part name entered by the user is in the `supplier_data`
    #    dictionary, we ask the user to enter a quantity.
    if part_input in new_data.keys():
        quantity_input = int(
            input(
                f"Please enter in a quantity to order ("
                f"{new_data[part_input]['quantity']:,} units available):"
            )
        )

        # 7. If the quantity entered by the user is greater than the quantity
        #    available for that part, we print an error message and ask the user
        #    to enter a part name again.
        if quantity_input > new_data[part_input]["quantity"]:
            print(
                f"Error: only {new_data[part_input]['quantity']} units are "
                f"available for {part_input}!"
            )
            continue
        # 8. If the quantity entered by the user is less than or equal to the
        #    quantity available for that part, we add the part and quantity 
        #    to the `order` dictionary, print the updated order, and update the 
        #    quantity available for that part in the `supplier_data` dictionary.
        else:
            order[part_input] = order.get(part_input, 0) + quantity_input
            print(
                f'\nYour order of {quantity_input:,} units for part "'
                f'{part_input}" was fullfilled!\n'
            )
            pprint.pprint("Updated order:")
            pprint.pprint(order)
            print("\n" + "=" * 50 + "\n")

            # Note: comment the next line if you don't want to update the
            # `supplier_data`
            #       inventory of each part, after an order gets placed.
            new_data[part_input]["quantity"] -= quantity_input

    # 9. If the user enters `quit` or `q`, we exit the `while` loop.
    elif part_input in ["quit", "q"]:
        inventory = False
    # 10. If the part name entered by the user is not in the `supplier_data`
    #    dictionary, we print an error message and ask the user to enter a part
    #    name again.
    else:
        print(
            f'Error: part "{part_input}" does not exist, choose one of the '
            f"following:\n- "
            + "\n- ".join(new_data["parts"])
            + "\n\nThen try again..."
        )

# 11. After the `while` loop, we calculate the total cost of the order.
order_cost = sum(
    new_data[key]["price"] * value if isinstance(new_data[key], dict) else 0
    for key, value in order.items()
)

# 12. If the total cost of the order is greater than 0, we print the order
#     and the total cost. Total cost only equals zero if no quantity for any
#     part is specified. 
if order_cost > 0:
    print(f"\n{' Your Order ':=^50}")
    pprint.pprint(order)
    print(f"Total Cost: ${order_cost:,.2f}")
# 13. If the total cost of the order is less than or equal to 0, meaning no
#     order was placed, we print a message saying that the user didn't
#     order any part.
else:
    print("You didn't order any part...")
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was something easy to get it to link up. Some of your code is too advanced (still thank you though, especially for the comments). I was able to get the part I was working on to work....now onto the rest. :)

Answer (score 2):

The error I see is in the line

```
if quantity_input >= new_data['sprocket']['quantity']:
                print("Error, only" + new_data['sprocket']['quantity'] + part_input + " 
                are available!")
```

Replace the first key with `part_input`
This should be more like this

```
if quantity_input >= new_data[part_input]['quantity']:
                print("Error, only" + new_data[part_input]['quantity'] + part_input + " 
                are available!")
```

And just for user-friendliness just add this line inside your first if

```
print(f'{part_input} has quantity {supplier_data_dict[part_input]["quantity"]}')
```

Also, you have a logic error since your dictionary has 'parts' as another key. I can tell that it should not be regarded as a part type. I hope it helps